# How to access docker url from windows host

Tags: php, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have a php project in localhost which I can access from `http://localhost:8000` and I have a service running in a docker container which I can access from `http://192.168.56.100:8080`. To access `http://192.168.56.100:8080` I must configure my browser under manual proxy like this( this is from firefox configuration)

```
http proxy: proxy.comp.mycompanyname.com
No proxy for: localhost, 127.0.0.1,192.168.56.0/24
```

If I configure my browser above way then I can access this service `http://192.168.56.100:8080` from browser.

Now the problem is, I want to connect to the service from my php project from localhost in windows machine. I tried this

```
$client = new Soapclient("http://192.168.56.100:8080");
```

This gives me error

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'SoapFault: Could not connect to host"
```

I think I am missing some proxy configuration somewhere but not sure where. How to solve this?

Running following command gives me this

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.56.100:2376           v1.12.3
```

And my docker compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  idtool3-mysql-gpas:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: tmf-gpas-1.7.8-mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "gpas_2016"
      volumes:
        - ./gpas/sqls:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      labels:
        - "service-name:gpas"
        - "service-type:db-srv"
        - "environment:test"

  idtool3-gpas-wildfly:
    image: tmfev/gpas:1.7.8
    container_name: tmf-gpas-1.7.8-wildfly
    links:
      - "idtool3-mysql-gpas:mysqldb"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - idtool3-mysql-gpas
    labels:
      - "service-name:gpas"
      - "service-type:app-srv"
      - "environment:test"
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "/opt/wait-for-it.sh mysqldb:3306 -t 120 && /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: If you access `http://192.168.56.100:8080` from your browser, do you get the WSDL file?  The `SoapClient` requires a WSDL document.

Comment: Yes I get the WSDL document. I think it has something to do with proxy or networking because, my project is in localhost not in a docker contianer but the wsdl service is inside docker container.

Comment: can you access it using `wget http://192.168.56.100:8080` from the command line?  It could be networking, but if you can ping that IP networking is working fine.